# Change current DataRowView to a specific DataRowView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datarowview

I would like to change the current DataRowView to a specific line, so I can set the value where I want to.

```
public void SetTimeFromTimer(DateTime date, string timeFromTimer)
{
     monthCalendar1.SetDate(date);
     dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
     dataGridView1.Rows[1].Selected = true;
     DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)BindingContext[repTimeTable].Current;
     rowView["zr"] = timeFromTimer;
}
```

Comment: Please post code rather than an image.

Comment: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 1];`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop through each column and assign the value of the current cell to the desired row's cell. The following code can help you.

```
public void ChangeRowValues(int parentRow, int rowToBeChanged)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[rowToBeChanged].Cells[i].Value = 
            dataGridView.Rows[parentRow].Cells[i].Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetTimeFromTimer(DateTime date, string timeFromTimer)
{
  monthCalendar1.SetDate(date);
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
  int rowIndex = repTimeTable.Rows.IndexOf(repTimeTable.Select($"zraufnr = '{GetProjectNumber}' AND zrpnr = '{GetPersonalNumber}'")[0]);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowIndex.ToString()))
  {
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[ColumnZrZeit.Index];
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView) BindingContext[repTimeTable].Current;
    rowView["zr"] = timeFromTimer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take into account that, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.